# Android - how to update textview from another class

Tags: java, android

I'm pulling my hair out over this for a few hours now.

I've an Android Wear device, where I have tracked sensor data. I've sent this data successfully to the paired smartphone, I can see the messages displayed in logcat on the phone.

However, I'm trying to append a textview on the phone to display the sensor data, but when I call the textview.append() it crashes with a null pointer exception.

Error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

The listenerService that is listening for changes, on the phone. This does work, I'm getting the correct info in logcat:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    retrieveMessage(messageEvent.getPath());
}

private void retrieveMessage(String message) {
    MainActivity sensorData = new MainActivity();
    sensorData.appendData(message);
}
```

And the receiving method in my MainActivity, even getting the correct 'message' here in logcat:

```
    public void appendData(String message) {

    Log.d("MESSAGE", message);
    sensorList.append("\n" + " DISPLAY PLS :  " + message);
}
```

I've correctly inflated the the layout from within the onCreate() method in my MainActivity and I can append to this TextView from within this method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
sensorList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorListView);
    sensorList.setText("\n" + "On create");
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sensorListView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Sensors" />
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Could you add the full stack and the appropriated line numbers?

Comment: You might be able to use an interface with a callback to set the textview. It's similar to the "interacting with fragments" example on the Android docs

Comment: Actually, your problem is that you explicitly make a new activity at  `new MainActivity();` Shouldn't you be making an Intent to start MainActivity and passing your data through it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, I didn't spot that! Long day...

Comment: Welcome. I'm not sure exactly what code you need, so I don't feel comfortable leaving a full answer.

Comment: @mangledBadger can you post your MainActivity xml???

Comment: Done, xml added as request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with BroadcastReceiver, here is the sample code:

**Phone Side**

```
    public MainActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    public static final String ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED = "changed";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        sensorList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorListView);
        sensorList.setText("\n" + "On create");
        ...
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String content = intent.getStringExtra("content");
            sensorList.setText("");
        }
    };

}


public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    ...

    public static final String ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED = "changed";

    ...

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        ...
        retrieveMessage(message);
        ...
    }

    private void retrieveMessage(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("content", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , I had an idea it was to do with the BroadcastReceiver alright, but I couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks again.